# How to resolve "Minimum Font Size greater than current font size"?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, xcode-storyboard

I have a iOS project, Objective-C and storyboard base. I get this warning from Xcode when I build the project:

```
Main.storyboard: warning: Unsupported Configuration: Minimum Font Size greater than current font size
```

How do I find the offending component in my storyboard?

I could open the Main.storyboard in a text editor and do manual inspection and comparison but that seems like a lot of work for a large storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Open the storyboard in the source mode and look for the warning text as in the snapshot.
[image]

Comment: That sounds promising. I do not see what you see, though. There is no warnings in source view. Is this a setting somewhere? I am using Xcode 8.3.

Answer (score -1):

Set minimum font size < 1, Like 0,5
Minimum font size is a percentage of font size

Comment: No it's not. You're thinking of Minimum Font Scale. They are two different things.

Comment: My problem is not how to resolve it. My problem is to find the offending component.

Comment: I am seeing this exact same issue, and there are no warnings in my view as source view...